# Customizing Custom Style, singlespacing in quotes

Tags: line-spacing, quoting, report

I am using a custom class (provided [here](https://github.com/jolohaga/uclathes)) for my thesis. It is supposed to be based on the report class. It has two options a single and a double spacing option. I have to use doublespacing in the main text but I am allowed (and would like) to use singlespacing within the quote environment. The following works fine with `report` but not with my custom `uclathes` class.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{report} 
%\documentclass{uclathes} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Now I bet that's because of the different options and some custom settings in the class. Would anyone be able to help me out where to look in the `.cls` file for what I might need to tweak to get this to work?  I did find these lines

```
\def\quote{\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item[]}
\let\endquote=\endlist
```

in the file which seem to be relevant. But how would I have to manipulate them (or something else) so that my `\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing}` is respected?
Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you comment out those lines in the class? An MWE would be useful.

Comment: Sure. I've just left the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the
`\usepackage{setspace}%` and
`\usepackage{etoolbox}%` packages and then simply saying:

```
 \AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespacing}
```

That solved it without the need to modify anything in the class or class options files.